# How to prevent concurrent requests from sneaking by a check in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rails-activerecord

User has a balance of 1.

Two concurrent requests to make a transfer worth of 1 come in the following manner:

```
Transfer A passes validations as the user has enough balance
Transfer B passes validations as the user has enough balance
Transfer A is made
Transfer B is made
```

In a result, the user is left with a -1 balance, which obviously shouldn't happen.

How is this prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `with_lock` around the transaction.  This is just an example, assuming you have logic around an `account`:

```
account = user.account

account.with_lock do
  break unless account.balance.sufficient?

  account.transfer(amount)

  account.save!
end
```

Check out [the pessimistic locking documentation.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html)